# How to stop view from reappearing on workbench restart?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

How do I stop a view that has allowMultiple set to true from appearing upon workbench restart?

I've tried removing the view from the perspective, or hiding it within the finalize, but finalize is not called upon on system exit.

I've also tried hiding it in the constructor or in the `createPartControl()`, but that doesn't work, because the view isn't even created while it is just tabbed, and none of its content is showing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked it up and found [this](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_views.html)

It seems that there is an attribute of the `org.eclipse.ui.views` extension called `restorable`

> - **restorable** - flag indicating whether this view allows to be restored upon workbench restart. If set to false, the view will not be open
>     after a workbench restart. The default is true.